# Avoiding Contingency Table for SQL Geography:Point Distance by Joining two tables

Tags: mysql, geolocation

I've got a problem converning a sql statement. I've got two tables cities and persons, which each has got a Point-column.

I've already got a working distance function, but now I wanna select all persons who are within a specific distance of one city and don't want to make the contingency table of cities and persons, which is like

---

`SELECT c.name, COUNT(p.id) AS number, 
glength( LineStringFromWKB( LineString( GeomFromText( astext( PointFromWKB( c.geoLocation ) ) ) , GeomFromText( astext( PointFromWKB( p.geoLocation ) ) ) ) ) )  AS distance 
FROM City c, Person p
Having distance < 100
Order by distance ASC`

There must be a more efficient way to do this. Thanks a lot for any comment.

Comment: Why is there a `COUNT` when there is no grouping?
What is the data type of the `geoLocation` fields?

Comment: I forgot the GroupBy-Clause. Fields are Point, like written in description